# Looping Through Multiple Access 2016 Tables to Create a Concatenated String Based on a Common Key In Each Table

Tags: ms-access, vba

The Situation:

I have three tables of which each entry in each table holds a common value in column 1, named **Key** (begining at 0 and incremented by +1 each entry).  I am trying to concatenate a string consisting of each field value, in each table, at a specific row **(i)** based on the common "key" value in all three tables.

```
Dim dB As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim fld As DAO.Field

Dim outputTextstring As String

Set dB = CurrentDb

    i = 4

    Set rs = dB.OpenRecordset("TableOne")
    rs.FindFirst "[Key] = " & i
    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        If outputTextstring = "" then
            outputTextstring = fld.Value
        Else
            outputTextString = outputTextString & "|" & fld.Value
        End If
    Next
    rs.Close

    Set rs = dB.OpenRecordset("TableTwo")
    rs.FindFirst "[Key] = " & i
    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        If outputTextstring = "" then
            outputTextstring = fld.Value
        Else
            outputTextString = outputTextString & "|" & fld.Value
        End If
    Next
    rs.Close

    Set rs = dB.OpenRecordset("TableThree")
    rs.FindFirst "[Key] = " & i
    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        If outputTextstring = "" then
            outputTextstring = fld.Value
        Else
            outputTextString = outputTextString & "|" & fld.Value
        End If
    Next
    rs.Close
```

I get a Run-time error '3251' on the .FindFirst line, stating "Operation is not supported for this type of object."  I am guessing this is a syntax error but any help would be appreciated.

**Edit: (Additional Question)**
After searching several other threads the problem might be the fact that the field "**Key**" is a Short Text Data type when viewed in the Design View of the Table, and data I am searching for or "**i**" is an integer or a string when I declare it.  Is it true like I have read in other threads that "Access sucks" and the two data types cannot intermingle?

Comment: I _really_ start to think you should read more into data normalization. Considering your previous question and this question, it's likely you're storing things in different columns that should actually sit in different rows.

Comment: I had actually explored that avenue until I realized how I wanted to use the data in the tables later in my program.  I appreciate how you looked at the situation from a different prespective, and I will reconsider that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I started searching around for other methods of identifying records to avoid using the methods that I received an error for, and despite having not found the "why" the error occured int he first place, I fixed the problem indirectly.  Below is my soultion after I added a primary key to each table:

```
Dim dB As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim fld As DAO.Field

'I used this to skip the first two fields (the primary key and a group tag)
x = 0

Set rs = dB.OpenRecordset("TableOne")
rs.Index = "PrimaryKey"
rs.MoveFirst
rs.MoveLast
'iStr is a loop incrementor turned into a string each loop to identify the key #
rs.Seek "=", Val(iStr)

For Each fld In rs.Fields
    If x > 1 Then
        If outputStr = "" Then
            outputStr = fld.Value
        Else
            outputStr = outputStr & "|" & fld.Value
        End if
    End If
    If Not fld.Value = "" Then
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next fld
rs.Close
'repeat for the other two tables to concatenate all three strings
```

Its simple and it works, but I do appreciate all the help and feedback.  Thanks much everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be better off creating a query in Access to give you the results you need. If you know that all 3 tables are always to going to have a record with the given `ID`, you can create 1 query that has the fields concatenated as you need:

[image: Query]
[image: Query Results]

If it's possible that some tables don't have a value for the given key, then that makes the problem a bit more complex, but your job is still easier with queries that concatenate the fields as you need.

Another thing to consider: Your current code will include the key 3 times in your output text. If that's not necessary, you can exclude the key from your output (as I did in the query above, or you can start your VBA field-looping at 1, to exclude the first Key field).

Comment: It would be my first time creating a query but I will give it a try.  I will let you know if it works.

Comment: This solution could work, however i don't think it would scale very well. Any additions or deletions of fields would have to be edited in the query EVERY time you made a change.

Comment: At this point if I use a query I must explain the situation a little further.  I am looking to make my string from three tables, compare it to existing string, then if it doesn't match, compare it to the next record or concatenated string from the same process.  I am unsure if I can query within a loop like that.  Any thoughts?

Comment: It would be a static table used to compare an existing string to what is in the three tables.  The existing table entries would not change.  Existing stings that do no match the concatenated entries would then become new entries in all three tables.

Comment: This all comes about due to the limit of 255 fields in a table.  I should just use Excel and make one large table.

Comment: __HarmLeastOne__,  where is the "existing string" coming from that you're comparing to values in the tables? There might be a better way to do this comparison than concatenating fields in all 3 tables.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem seems to lie in the find first, then here is a similar modification to a OpenRecordset that I have in one of my applications.

```
Dim dB As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

Set dB = CurrentDB()    
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TableOne WHERE Key = " & i

Set rs = dB.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

With rs
    If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
        .MoveFirst
        While (Not .EOF)
            For Each fld In rs.Fields
                If outputTextstring = "" then
                    outputTextstring = fld.Value
                Else
                    outputTextString = outputTextString & "|" & fld.Value
                End If
            .MoveNext
        Wend
    End If
    .Close
End With
```

If the end result is to just find the FIRST record, then you can simply change the SQL Statement to only look for the first one it finds

```
strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableOne WHERE Key = " & i
```

**EDIT:**

I have updated my answer to include the declarations. However whenever working with SQL queries in VBA, I would highly suggest to first create your query as an Access Query, testing and verifying the results, then copy the SQL Text in your VBA after you have verified. This is to remove the headache of figuring out if its a VBA problem or SQL Syntax issue.

Comment: i just started programming in Access and I am not familiar with SQL in any manner.  Is there any other declarations I must make at the begining of my function to use SQL Methods/ Operations?

Comment: When the line "Set rs = dB.OpenRecordSet(strSQL)" runs I get  a "Data type mismiatch in criteria expression."  Error 3464., and your internal for loop doesn't end so I closed it.  Any thoughts on the error?

Comment: I have the strSQL declared as a String.

Comment: Might it have something to do with having rs As a DAO.Recordset earlier in my function?

Comment: @HarmLeastOne please review my answer again. I have updated it with clarifications as well as a suggestion. Sounds like you issue is just in your query syntax/data type issue

Comment: I have tried the strSQL method above and tried the suggested syntax corrections.  Still no luck and still the same error.  As I mentioned in the query answer, what I am trying to accomplish to much more complex.  Take a look if you have the time and see what I am really trying to do.

Comment: My suggestion of making a MS Access Query was to ensure you that those were the results you wanted your VBA to concatenate. Also to make sure the query worked. Did you make the query and verify the results? if your getting the same error THERE (Data type mismatch), then you either need to change the datatype of your field, or cast you "i" as a matching data type. SQL wont automatically detect datatype differences